Flutter atan2 Angle Calculation for Rotating Line - 90 Degree Offset Issue
I'm building a Flutter app that allows users to rotate a line within a circle using a GestureDetector. The angle of the line is calculated based on the user's touch position. However, I'm encountering a persistent 90-degree offset issue.
Expected Behavior:

The line should rotate smoothly from the exact point where the user touches the dot at the end of the line.
The angle displayed should accurately reflect the line's rotation, normalized to the range of 0-180 degrees (for both clockwise and counter-clockwise rotations).

Actual Behavior:

When the user touches the dot and starts dragging, the line jumps forward by 90 degrees from the touch position.
The angle calculation seems to be off by 90 degrees.

What I've Tried:
I've tried various approaches to adjust the angle calculation, including:

Using atan2 to get the angle from the touch coordinates.
Adding 90 degrees to the calculated angle to align with Flutter's coordinate system.
Constraining the line's endpoint to the circle's circumference to prevent resizing.
Normalizing the displayed angle to the 0-180 degree range.
I've carefully reviewed the code and made multiple corrections, but the 90-degree offset issue persists.

The code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Angle Inputter'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _angle = 0.0;
  bool _dotPressed = false;

  bool _isPointInsideDot(Offset point, Offset dotCenter, double radius) {
    return (point - dotCenter).distance <= radius;
  }

  Rect _getDotTouchTarget(Offset dotCenter, double dotRadius) {
    const double touchTargetPadding = 24.0;
    return Rect.fromCenter(
      center: dotCenter,
      width: 2 * (dotRadius + touchTargetPadding),
      height: 2 * (dotRadius + touchTargetPadding),
    );
  }

    void _updateAngle(Offset position) {
    final Offset center = Offset(100, 100); // Circle center
    final double radius = 100; // Circle radius

    // Calculate angle 
    double newAngle = (atan2(position.dy - center.dy, position.dx - center.dx) * 180 / pi) % 360; 

    // Constrain line endpoint to the circle
    final double dx = radius * cos(newAngle * pi / 180);
    final double dy = radius * sin(newAngle * pi / 180);
    final Offset constrainedPosition = center + Offset(dx, dy);

    // NOW adjust for Flutter's coordinate system (after constraining)
    newAngle = (newAngle + 90) % 360;

    setState(() {
      _angle = newAngle;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double displayAngle = _angle <= 180 ? _angle : 360 - _angle;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Text(
              'Angle: ${displayAngle.toInt()}°',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onPanStart: (details) {
                    final dotRadius = _dotPressed ? 12.0 : 6.0;
                    final Offset center = Offset(100, 100);
                    final Offset dotCenter = Offset(
                      center.dx + 100 * cos(_angle * pi / 180),
                      center.dy + 100 * sin(_angle * pi / 180),
                    );

                    if (_getDotTouchTarget(dotCenter, dotRadius).contains(details.localPosition)) {
                      setState(() {
                        _dotPressed = true;
                        Vibration.vibrate();
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  onPanUpdate: (details) {
                    if (_dotPressed) {
                      _updateAngle(details.localPosition);
                    }
                  },
                  onPanEnd: (details) {
                    setState(() {
                      _dotPressed = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    size: const Size(200, 200),
                    painter: AnglePainter(_angle, _dotPressed),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double angle;
  final bool dotPressed;

  AnglePainter(this.angle, this.dotPressed);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double radius = size.width / 2;
    final Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    // Draw the blue circle
    final circlePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, circlePaint);

    // Draw the green reference line
    final referenceLinePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;
    canvas.drawLine(center, Offset(center.dx + radius, center.dy), referenceLinePaint);

    // Calculate the end point of the red line based on the angle
    final double radian = angle * (pi / 180);
    final Offset endPoint = Offset(
      center.dx + radius * cos(radian),
      center.dy + radius * sin(radian),
    );

    // Draw the red line that rotates 
    final linePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0;
    canvas.drawLine(center, endPoint, linePaint);

    // Draw the blue dot at the end of the red line
    final dotPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawCircle(endPoint, dotPressed ? 12.0 : 6.0, dotPaint);

    // Draw the angle text on top
    final textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: '${(angle <= 180 ? angle : 360 - angle).toStringAsFixed(1)}°',
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
    );
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: textSpan,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width,
    );
    final textOffset = Offset(center.dx - textPainter.width / 2, center.dy - radius - textPainter.height - 10);
    textPainter.paint(canvas, textOffset);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}


try using final angle = (position - center).direction; // range: -π .. π

As you said this happens because the angle calculation used to determine the line's rotation is consistently off by 90 degrees due to a misalignment with Flutter's coordinate system.
_updateAngle method needs to be updated like this:
void _updateAngle(Offset position) {
  final Offset center = Offset(100, 100); // Circle center
  final double radius = 100; // Circle radius

  // Calculate angle using atan2
  double newAngle =
      atan2(position.dy - center.dy, position.dx - center.dx) * 180 / pi;

  // Adjust for Flutter's coordinate system
  newAngle = (newAngle + 360) % 360; // Normalize to 0-360 degrees

  setState(() {
    _angle = newAngle;
  });
}

Here is the fixed code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Angle Inputter'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _angle = 0.0;
  bool _dotPressed = false;

  bool _isPointInsideDot(Offset point, Offset dotCenter, double radius) {
    return (point - dotCenter).distance <= radius;
  }

  Rect _getDotTouchTarget(Offset dotCenter, double dotRadius) {
    const double touchTargetPadding = 24.0;
    return Rect.fromCenter(
      center: dotCenter,
      width: 2 * (dotRadius + touchTargetPadding),
      height: 2 * (dotRadius + touchTargetPadding),
    );
  }

  void _updateAngle(Offset position) {
    final Offset center = Offset(100, 100); // Circle center
    final double radius = 100; // Circle radius

    // Calculate angle using atan2
    double newAngle = atan2(position.dy - center.dy, position.dx - center.dx) * 180 / pi;

    // Adjust for Flutter's coordinate system
    newAngle = (newAngle + 360) % 360; // Normalize to 0-360 degrees

    setState(() {
      _angle = newAngle;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double displayAngle = _angle <= 180 ? _angle : 360 - _angle;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Text(
              'Angle: ${displayAngle.toInt()}°',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onPanStart: (details) {
                    final dotRadius = _dotPressed ? 12.0 : 6.0;
                    final Offset center = Offset(100, 100);
                    final Offset dotCenter = Offset(
                      center.dx + 100 * cos(_angle * pi / 180),
                      center.dy + 100 * sin(_angle * pi / 180),
                    );

                    if (_getDotTouchTarget(dotCenter, dotRadius).contains(details.localPosition)) {
                      setState(() {
                        _dotPressed = true;
                        Vibration.vibrate();
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  onPanUpdate: (details) {
                    if (_dotPressed) {
                      _updateAngle(details.localPosition);
                    }
                  },
                  onPanEnd: (details) {
                    setState(() {
                      _dotPressed = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    size: const Size(200, 200),
                    painter: AnglePainter(_angle, _dotPressed),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double angle;
  final bool dotPressed;

  AnglePainter(this.angle, this.dotPressed);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double radius = size.width / 2;
    final Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    // Draw the blue circle
    final circlePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, circlePaint);

    // Draw the green reference line
    final referenceLinePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;
    canvas.drawLine(center, Offset(center.dx + radius, center.dy), referenceLinePaint);

    // Calculate the end point of the red line based on the angle
    final double radian = angle * (pi / 180);
    final Offset endPoint = Offset(
      center.dx + radius * cos(radian),
      center.dy + radius * sin(radian),
    );

    // Draw the red line that rotates 
    final linePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0;
    canvas.drawLine(center, endPoint, linePaint);

    // Draw the blue dot at the end of the red line
    final dotPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawCircle(endPoint, dotPressed ? 12.0 : 6.0, dotPaint);

    // Draw the angle text on top
    final textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: '${(angle <= 180 ? angle : 360 - angle).toStringAsFixed(1)}°',
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
    );
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: textSpan,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width,
    );
    final textOffset = Offset(center.dx - textPainter.width / 2, center.dy - radius - textPainter.height - 10);
    textPainter.paint(canvas, textOffset);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

